# SOAP fault redirected to a custom page

Tags: php, soap

FIrst of all i want to ask if its ok to redirect the SOAP fault to a custom page.

```
catch (SoapFault $exception) {
      $exception->getMessage();
            exit;
  }
?>
```

And now the question. How can i set a redirect for all the exceptions catched in the above code.

Comment: @jazzurro & co what is unclear for you guys on a answered question ? :-?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So that's 2 questions really =)

Anyway, in reply to your first question:

#### Is it ok to redirect the SOAP fault to a custom page

The answer is "it depends" - i.e. it depends on whether your users are going to want to see a custom error page or not - or if it's useful for them to see it (or not).

For instance, you could handle the error by staying on the page and displaying an on-screen message. Alternatively, it might make perfect sense to go to a custom error page and stop there.
You don't provide any contextual information about the system or what is being done to make it easy to say *Yes* or *No*.

#### How to set a redirect:

To redirect to another page, simply use the `header` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)
If you want to have a separate page for the SOAP errors, then create it and set the redirect in your catch:

```
catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    header('Location: soaperror.php');
}
```

so that would take care of it, but wouldn't help much in diagnosing the error - a better way might be to pass the error code or message to the custom page and display it somewhere along with some suitable text.

Alternatively, if you want to use a "custom error page" you can use solutions like [this one](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Custom_error_pages) from the Dreamhost wiki.